# How to "rotate" on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to maximize minimum pairwise "angle" with set of known vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces

Say I have $n$ vectors $\{{\bf v}_1,\cdots,{\bf v}_n\}$ which are of unit length: $\|{\bf v}_k\|_2 = 1$ and I want to find new vectors $\{{\bf w}_1,\cdots,{\bf w}_n\}$ by "rotation" i.e. some lenght-preserving linear operator $\bf O$: $${\bf w}_k  = {\bf O v}_k$$ Then I suppose what I want to do is

$$\min_{{\bf O \in SO}(n)} \left(\max_{k,i} \left({{\bf v}_i}^T{\bf O}{\bf v}_k\right)\right)$$

However I am not so sure of how to solve that. Any pointers?

Comment: What it sounds like you're asking I would formalize as something like $\arg\max_{\mathbf{T}\in \mathbf{SO}(n)}\{\min_{i\neq j} \{\mathbf{v}_i\cdot \mathbf{Tv}_j\}\}$ assuming the $\mathbf{v}_i$ all have the same length.  That's what your words sound like to me which looks like it contradicts the formulas you have.

Comment: Yes you are right. The variables of min and max are of course wrong. Will edit.